# Postgres insert function by aggregating data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have got two tables, 'page_visits' and 'comments', which store new webpage visits and new comments, respectively.

#### PAGE_VISITS

| id | page_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.779Z |
| 2 | 1442 | 2021-12-02T02:25:32.219Z |
| 3 | 1111 | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.214Z |

#### COMMENTS

| id | page_id | ... | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1024 | ... | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.779Z |
| 2 | 1111 | ... | 2021-12-02T02:25:32.219Z |
| 3 | 3849 | ... | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.214Z |

I want to aggregate the data from both the tables in the past 1 hour to use for analytics, such that it looks like the table below.

#### PAGE_DATA

| page_id | visit_count | comment_count | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1024 | 14 | 3 | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.779Z |
| 1111 | 11 | 8 | 2021-12-02T02:25:32.219Z |
| 3849 | 1 | 0 | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.214Z |
| 2412 | 0 | 1 | 2021-12-02T04:55:26.779Z |

```
SELECT page_visits.page_id
     , COUNT(page_visits.id)    AS visitCount
     , COALESCE(cmts.cmt_cnt,0) AS commentCount
  FROM page_visits
LEFT OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT page_id
              , COUNT(*) AS cmt_cnt
           FROM comments
          WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR'
         GROUP
             BY page_id
       ) AS cmts
    ON cmts.page_id = page_visits.page_id
 WHERE page_visits.created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR'
GROUP
    BY page_visits.page_id, cmts.cmt_cnt;
```

I have the above code as of now, however, it only prints the row when comment_count is null, but it does not do the same when visit_count is 0 and comment_count is > 0.
My first question is, how do I get it to print even when visit_count results as 0.
Because someone could have gone on to the page the hour before but only made a comment later on.

Secondly, I am trying to run this code every hour with the use of pg_cron and I know that I can run a function directly in a cron scheduler, however, I am unable to turn the above code into a working postgres function that inserts a new row into the 'page_data' table each time its called.

Could someone help me out with these 2 issues? Thank you.

Comment: Add the details of your page table also in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider full join on two aggregates

```sql
SELECT page_visits.page_id 
     , COALESCE(vsts.vst_cnt, 0) AS visitCount 
     , COALESCE(cmts.cmt_cnt, 0) AS commentCount
FROM (
    SELECT page_id
         , COUNT(*) AS vst_cnt 
    FROM page_visits 
    WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR' 
    GROUP BY page_id
   ) AS vsts
FULL OUTER JOIN ( 
    SELECT page_id 
         , COUNT(*) AS cmt_cnt 
    FROM comments
    WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR'
    GROUP BY page_id 
   ) AS cmts
 ON cmts.page_id = vsts.page_id
```

Alternatively, aggregate a UNION query of both tables:

```sql
SELECT page_id
     , SUM(vst_n) AS vst_cnt 
     , SUM(cmt_n) AS cmt_cnt
FROM (
    SELECT page_id, 1 AS vst_n, 0 AS cmt_n
    FROM page_visits 
    WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR'
 
    UNION ALL

    SELECT page_id, 0 AS vst_n, 1 AS cmt_n
    FROM comments 
    WHERE created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 HOUR' 
   ) AS sub
GROUP BY page_id
```

Regarding last question, if I understand you, simply run an insert-select query from above query. Not quite sure how you aggregated `created_at`, but add a `MIN` or `MAX` to above aggregations and include an additional column below:

```sql
INSERT INTO page_data (page_id, visit_count, comment_count)
SELECT ...above query...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The 1st answer didn't quite work for me because page_visits.page_id does not necessarily contain a specific page_id that lies in the comments table. This is due to the fact that someone may have visited the page the hour before, but only commented later. So, in such cases, it returned a null for page_id. The second answer, however, works exactly as intended, so thank you for that. May I ask why add the MIN/MAX to the aggregations?

Comment: I had a slight naming issue with `FULL OUTER JOIN` query. Can you check and report errors? This type of join will return either matched or unmatched page_ids between visits and comments (i.e., NULL in either table). It should return same result as `UNION` query.

Comment: And min/max is to fill the `created_at` field in you final `page_data` table. Since this table aggregates by `page_id`, it was unclear how you achieve this date data. Maybe `MIN(created_at)` could work? Or `MAX`? But be sure to add field in underlying subqueries.